# compare two columns (in two files), then print the similar lines and different lines

Tags: python, csv, python-itertools

I have two files that contain two columns for each one, in the first column the lines are often similar.

file1.csv

```
C(2)—C(1) 1.5183
C(3)—C(2) 1.49
C(3)—C(1) 1.4991
O(4)—C(3) 1.4104
H(10)—O(4) 0.964
C(2)—C(1)—C(3) 59.19
C(3)—C(1)—H(5) 118.4
```

file2.csv

```
C(2)—C(1) 1.5052
C(3)—C(2) 1.505
C(3)—C(1) 1.5037
S(4)—C(3) 1.7976
H(10)—S(4) 1.3445
C(2)—C(1)—H(6) 117.68
C(2)—C(1)—C(3) 60.3
C(3)—C(1)—H(5) 116.99
```

here is a python script "using itertools" which compares the first colone in file1.csv and file2.csv and then prints the lines similar.

```
import itertools

files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']
d = {}

for fi, f in enumerate(files):
    fh = open(f)
    for line in fh:
        sl = line.split()
        name = sl[0]
        val = float(sl[1])
        if name not in d:
            d[name] = {}
        if fi not in d[name]:
            d[name][fi] = []
        d[name][fi].append(val)
    fh.close()

for name, vals in d.items():
    if len(vals) == len(files):
        for var in itertools.product(*vals.values()):
            if max(var) - min(var) <= 20:
                out = '{}\t{}'.format(name, "\t".join(map(str, var)))
                print(out)
                break
```

output.csv

```
C(2)-C(1)        1.5183   1.5052
C(3)-C(2)        1.49     1.505
C(3)-C(1)        1.4991   1.5037
C(2)-C(1)-C(3)   59.19    60.3
C(3)-C(1)-H(5)   118.4    116.99
```

but I do not find an idea to print also the different lines.

my desired output:

```
similar_lines
C(2)-C(1)           1.5183    1.5052
C(3)-C(2)           1.49      1.505
C(3)-C(1)           1.4991    1.5037
C(2)-C(1)-C(3)      59.19     60.3
C(3)-C(1)-H(5)      118.4     116.99

different_lines
O(4)-C(3)           1.4104      non
H(10)-O(4)          0.964       non
S(4)-C(3)            non       1.7976
H(10)-S(4)           non       1.3445
C(2)-C(1)-H(6)       non       117.68
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools, csv
file1 = [i+[True] for i in list(csv.reader(open('filename1.csv')))]
file2 = [i+[False] for i in list(csv.reader(open('filename2.csv')))]
new_data = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(file1+file2, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
similar = ['{} {}'.format(a, '     '.join(h for _, h, flag in b)) for a, b in new_data if len(b) > 1]
different = ['{} {}'.format(a, 'non  {}'.format(b[0][1]) if not b[0][-1] else '{}     non'.format(b[0][1])) for a, b in new_data if len(b) == 1]
last_output = 'similar_lines\n{}\n\ndifferent_lines\n{}'.format('\n'.join(similar), '\n'.join(different))
```

Output:

```
similar_lines
C (2)-C(1) 1.5183     1.5052
C (2)-C(1)-C(3) 59.19     60.3
C (3)-C(1) 1.4991     1.5037
C (3)-C(1)-H(5) 118.4     116.99
C (3)-C(2) 1.49     1.505

different_lines
C (2)-C(1)-H(6) non  117.68
H (10)-O(4) 0.964     non
H (10)-S(4) non  1.3445
O (4)-C(3) 1.4104     non
S (4)-C(3) non  1.7976
```

Comment: I did not find the same results

Comment: @ahmedredha Is the data in your `.csv` files exactly the same as you posted? I ran the results with the data you posted, and achieved the result posted above.

Comment: no, I moved the second and third columns, in order to understand my question

Comment: Ajax1234 now i have reposted the two files file1.csv and file2.csv that i originally used. but still no results as in your case.

Comment: @ahmedredha Strange, what specifically is wrong with the output?

Comment: i do not know. I do not know, I use ubuntu, python2 and python3